# Терминал выдает invalid syntax на "рабочую" функцию

Tags: python, syntax

Написал функцию для сохранения актуального времени и какого-то сообщения в файл. В функции есть строчка result = f'{current_time} - {message}'. Заранее скажу - в интерпретаторе функция отрабатывает без ошибок. Эту функцию, записанную в файл **core.py** импортировал в файл **main.py**. При запуске через терминал выдает SyntaxError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from core import create_file, create_folder, get_list, delet_file, copy_file, save_info
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/console_file_manager/core.py", line 46
    result = f'{current_time} - {message}'
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```py
def save_info(message):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    result = f'{current_time} - {message}'
    with open('log.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f
        f.write(result+'\n')
    print (result)
```

Comment: может быть from './core' import ...

Comment: так, вроде, ошибку в core и показывает

Comment: Кажется у вас python2, а f-строки появились в python 3.6 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings